# Does OSX have a "plug & play driver" concept?

Tags: macos, driver

Windows when it detects an unsupported device, it requests a driver from the user. Does OSX have a place when I can find information on unrecognised devices?

Comment: I recently asked a question about [an unsupported device](http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/2603/how-do-i-tell-os-x-that-an-arbitrary-controller-is-a-midi-device), but the one thing I never did was look and see if it was listed in the System Profiler. Are you actually having a problem with getting a device to be recognized? Maybe more detail about the actual problem would allow us to help you better.

Answer (score 1):

For local devices/services you can use the System-Profiler to check all available devices in your computer. Most devices are directly supported through Apple and thus you don't have to install any drivers. For some 3rd party tools like external Audio/Video systems you may have to install the drivers supplied with the tools, but you should be able to discover the devices through the System-Profiler.

For devices and services available through the network Apple has developed a plug and play system called [Bonjour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_%28software%29). It allows zeroconf of e.g. printers and file-sharing services. There is a 3rd pary tool called [Bonjour Browser](http://www.tildesoft.com/) which is advertised to be able to discover all services/devices available through Bonjour. I never used the software and can't comment on how well it works.

Comment: Your answer is off topic. I am not talking about network at all.

Comment: You asked about detection of unsupported devices. Microsoft introduced the name "Plug & Play" for discovering new devices and automatically configure them or ask the user for drivers. For Mac OS, the similar concept is Bonjour. If you just want to see which devices are attached to your Mac, use System-Profiler.

Comment: Hold on a second. ffeldhaus' answer is half correct, the mention of System Profiler is correct. The first half (Bonjour) is completely off base though.

Comment: I rephrased my answer to more prominently highlight the direct answer to the question and explain, why I mentioned Bonjour. As far as I understand it, Bonjour is a protocol for discovering services and devices available through the network like e.g. printers and allows for zeroconf and automatic driver installation, which I understood to be part of the question.

Comment: @ffeldhaus For completeness your addition of Bonjour rounds off the answer nicely for me.  Nowhere does the OP suggest he is talking USB only, for example.  I think the confusion is that on Windows Plug and Play refers to local devices only, but there is also Universal Plug and PLay which extends this to the network and will often find your router listed etc.

Comment: "PnP" was a MSFT brand name for auto-assigning ISA addresses in Win95 (akin to what PCI does natively), so technically OS X (which doesn't support ISA devices) doesn't need this. In the broader sense, though, ZC is a PnP-type technology. It was intended by its creator to let you have "a row of identical universal IP communications ports, where I can connect anything I want to any port" (yes, including your keyboard and mouse): http://www.stuartcheshire.org/TheIdeaBasket.html